# Query - Between operator on PHP ADODB

Tags: php, sql, date, adodb, between

I have a form with two datepicker (dd/mm/yyyy). 
**Code:**

```
<label for="from">From Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

And I try to select this range of data with PHP. **But there are an error.**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message
>   '**Source:** Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
>   Drivers
> **Description:** [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft
>   Access] Tipi di dati non corrispondenti nell'espressione criterio.' in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\DinamicoWeb\index.php:43 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\DinamicoWeb\index.php(43):
>   com->execute('SELECT [Id Ord]...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\DinamicoWeb\index.php on
>   line 43

**So this is my php file** (work perfectly without date):

```
$input=$_POST['input'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$numero1=$_POST['numero1'];
$numero2=$_POST['numero2'];
$data1=$_POST['from'];
$data2=$_POST['to'];

if (empty($input)) {
    $sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE [Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo' OR [Data Ord] BETWEEN '$data1' AND '$data2'";
} else {
    $sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE [Indirizzo] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo'" OR [Data Ord] BETWEEN '$data1' AND '$data2'";
}
```

**line 43:**

```
$rs = $con->execute($sql);
```

**Form:** (not calculate the number from 1 to 100) 
 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code is an open invitation to SQL injection. You should use parametrized queries.

Then, if the DB is MS Access, and `[Data Ord]` is **date** type, in the SQL you should surround your dates with `#` and not `'`,  and also format them properly as follow : `MM/DD/YYYY`

Something **like** this.

```
$input=$_POST['input'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$numero1=$_POST['numero1'];
$numero2=$_POST['numero2'];
$data1=date('m/d/Y', strtotime($_POST['from']));;
$data2=date('m/d/Y', strtotime($_POST['to']));;

if (empty($input)) {
    $sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE [Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo' OR [Data Ord] BETWEEN #$data1# AND #$data2#";
} else {
    $sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE [Indirizzo] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo'" OR [Data Ord] BETWEEN #$data1# AND #$data2#";
}
```

I have no idea how your POST data is formated so you might have to change the way I formatted the dates

Comment: Thanks! It's correct, I change only `$data1=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($_POST['from']));;` because my date format is DD/MM/YYYY. 
And, to operate between the two numbers, I have to convert number1 and number1 in numeric format? So: `$numero2=int($_POST['numero2']);` ? :)